# how to get the value from input fields and write to json file?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I'm trying to understand how to work with data and so I'm trying to get the value from input fields and write to the json file, but it doesn't work, I would be glad if you help me with this.

**html:**

```
<form id="myForm">
  <label for="yourname">Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name" id="name">
  <label for="yourname">Last name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="last-name" placeholder="last name" id="lastName">
  <input type="submit" value="send" id="btn">
</form>
```

**js:**

```
$(function() {
    $("#myForm").submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "form.php",
            data: $("#myForm").serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                var name = $("#name").val("");
                var lastName = $("#lastName").val("");
            }
        });
        return false; 
    });
});
```

php:

```
<?php 
$ToEmail = 'names.json'; 
$EmailSubject = 'форма'; 
$mailheader = "From: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n";
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Name: ".$_POST["name"].""; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Last-Name: ".$_POST["last-name"]."";
mail($ToEmail, $EmailSubject, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader) or die ("Failure"); 
?>
```

Comment: You can't write into json in clientside. Are you using a server for saving json details?

Comment: yes, i use a server

Comment: so, what's not working then? maybe you might send the server code.

Comment: what about this version if i use a php file to send a data to json file (like a form)

Comment: are you trying to save a json file or trying to send a email from your form?

Comment: I'm trying to send data to json file :)

Comment: You need to rewrite your server PHP code to handle JSON input. I'm not PHP dev, but it looks like you need to parse data object that you send to server.
Current PHP implementation looks like you read values from standard POST.

Comment: I need that I parse this without php code only, but i don't know how I edit my file, in this version when you fill in the form and try to send, the form doesn't send anything, you just click on the button and nothing is happenning

Comment: First, use developer tools in browser (F12) and check for JS errors. When no errors, then try tool like Fiddler to see where and how it was posted to server. If those two are ok, then you need to dig in PHP code to handle it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't write to JSON files directly with Javascript. You should create a PHP script that does this and then send the POST request to this PHP script.

EDIT: Here's a very simple script.

```
<?php file_put_contents("names.json","{\"name\":\"".$_POST["name"]."\",\"last-name\":\"".$_POST["last-name"]."\"}",FILE_APPEND); ?>
```

Comment: can you please write the simplest version of php code for this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 <?php

$inputArray = array(
    'name' => $_POST["name"],
    'last-name' => $_POST["last-name"],
    'email'=>$_POST["email"]
);
$myfile = fopen("myfile.json", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$text = json_encode($inputArray);

fwrite($myfile, $text);
fclose($myfile);

echo "file saved";
?>
```

Comment: Welcome mate. If it works for you accept my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Php script to write the received data into a json file.

Try using: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

As received data is in $_GET or $_POST, you can easily convert those arrays using the json_encode method: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php